# Applying IF Statement to entire column

Tags: google-sheets

I currently have an `IF` statement that checks a cell in column B if it is blank. If it is blank it returns `No` in the corresponding A cell.  If it does have a string, it returns `Yes`.

I currently have tried this as a basis:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(E2), "No", "Yes")
```

How would I apply this to the entire column?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula to do that.

### Formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B:B)=TRUE, "No", "Yes"))
```

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[IF for complete column](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdHhBR2dmOFpHbnVuMEtGQmprR1dqekE&usp=sharing)**